# Heat and External Hard Drive's Lifespan

Tags: external-hard-drive

I am looking to purchase a [external hard drive](http://amzn.com/B00834SJU8) and from what I read the biggest drawback to the drive is it doesn't have the best cooling.

My question is how much should I worry about the drive heating up and the heat hurting the lifespan of the drive?

Note: I plan to use it as mainly a backup drive not a full time drive.

Comment: If the drive vendor is selling the packaged drive, they're aware of any heat effects on the lifetime of the drive, and are unlikely to produce a poor combo that would produce too many warranty claims.  And I've had three separate drives totaling maybe 15 years of use, with no drive problems.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel said in his comment, the manufacturer (Seagate) has probably made a reasonable tradeoff in the design of the enclosure, and it should be pretty reliable.

Having said that, heat does negatively impact the life-span of hard drives so make sure that you've got the drive in a well ventilated area so it doesn't get hotter than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to consider about external hard drives is to not subject them to a lot of vibration and shock. This also reduces life.